# Use JavaScript or MVC razor to go back a page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

With the HTML tag `<a>` onclick should I use

```
onclick="history.go(-1);"
```

or

```
href="@Url.Action("index", "somecontroller")"
```

What is the actual difference between these two methods as seen by a browser?

Comment: Neither. If people want to go back then their browser has a perfectly good back button that interacts with their history in a way they understand.

Comment: If you are using razor why don't you use actionlinks? i.e. `@Html.ActionLink("About Page", "About")` with the first one being the title and the other being the corresponding controller. You can add a third parameter for the sub-view method.

Comment: There's a lot of issues with the code. `location.href` is *already* JavaScript, so the `javascript:` is a little late. Furthermore, you are assigning the return value of a function to `location.href` inside single quotes which treats it as a string.

Comment: Well what I have is a list of editable items. I go to edit one item from there this is a new page. I have a cancel and save button. The cancel sends the user back to the list.

Comment: I fixed the code so one is using the onclick and the other is using the action link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use:
***Action Links*** : which creates `<a href=".."></a>` tag automatically as

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

generates:

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
```

or

**Url.Action** as For example:

```
Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })
```

Comment: So you recommend using this razor vs the javascript onclick?

Comment: Yes Pure MVC @Xm7X :)

Comment: To backup your answer the href is more for just going to a link.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp  The onclick is more for executing a script.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp